# Default Params for a custom exception

Tags: php, symfony, exception

In my symfony4 project, I want to throw custom exceptions, so I created an Exception Class:

#### ApiException

```
namespace App\Utils;


class ApiException extends \Exception
{

    private $class;
    private $function;

    public function __construct(string $message, string $class, string $function, int $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null)
    {

        $this->class = $class;
        $this->function = $function;

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->class.'\\'.$this->function.', Line '.$this->line.': '.$this->message;
    }
}
```

#### Throw the Exception

`throw new ApiException('Please select a date between 1950 and 2050', __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);`

#### Output

`App\\Utils\\Api\\by_year, Line 43: Please select a date between 1950 and 2050`

which is exactly as I want it BUT, I'd like to avoid having to hand over `__CLASS__` and `__FUNCTION__` in my Exception throwing.
Where would I need to inject those two params in order to always have it available. Calling it within the Exception gives me Class name and Function name of the ExceptionClass, not the Class throwing it?

Comment: why do you even need to mess with your constructor? the exception backtrace will tell you all of this anyway! Why not ditch the constructor and just concat the message string instead? `throw new ApiException('Please select a date between 1950 and 2050 in ' . __CLASS__, '::' .__FUNCTION__);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common practice when throwing an exception is to include a full backtrace rather than just the class that threw it. PHP's `Exception` class has a native method for this: [`getTraceAsString`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php), so there's never a need to manually pass in a class or function name. You can amend your class as follows:

```
class ApiException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(string $message, int $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getTraceAsString().': '.$this->message;
    }
}
```

If you want to only show certain levels of the backtrace, there is also a [`getTrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php) method that returns the steps as an array, but in my opinion a full trace is always going to be more useful.

See https://3v4l.org/UHI08 for a full example

The output is almost identical to what PHP will show you for an uncaught exception.